# A VNC server is already running, but no lock file for that

Tags: files, vnc, lock

Although there is no X11 lock on display 12, vncserver can not start that display number due to a "VNC server that is running on 12".

```
# rm /tmp/.X12-lock
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/.X12-lock’: No such file or directory
# rm /tmp/.X11-unix/X12
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/.X11-unix/X12’: No such file or directory
# ps aux | grep Xvnc | grep :12
#
# su - metal3 -c "vncserver -geometry 1300x900 :12"
A VNC server is already running as :12

New 'hpc.test.com:10 (metal3)' desktop is hpc.test.com:10

Starting applications specified in /home/metal3/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/metal3/.vnc/hpc.test.com:10.log
```

Any more lock file that I have missed for killing?

Comment: Take a look at what ports are open, using `ss` or `netstat` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking the lock from VNC. VNC and SSH X forward both use X Window System's ports starting from 6000/tcp. So take a look at the 600x ports. It is very likely that 6012 is used by sshd.